# Как разбить код, чтобы MethodLength был хотя бы 15

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть консерн:

```
module Omniauthable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    def self.find_for_oauth(auth)
      authorization = Authorization.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid.to_s).first
      return authorization.user if authorization

      if auth.info.try(:email)
        email = auth.info[:email]
      else
        return false
      end

      user = User.where(email: email).first
      if user
        user.create_authorization(auth)
      else
        password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
        user = User.new(email: email,
                        password: password,
                        password_confirmation: password)
        if user.valid?
          user.save!
          user.create_authorization(auth)
        else
          return false
        end
      end
      user
    end

    def create_authorization(auth)
      authorizations.create(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
    end
  end
end
```

Нужно разделить `self.find_for_oauth(auth)`, чтобы количество строк в методе было хотя бы 15.

Comment: На вас [`rubocop`](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/config/default.yml#L849) ругается что ли? :)

Comment: Да, ругается, я в конфиге увеличил Metrics/MethodLength, но это ведь не решение проблемы, хотелось бы разделить как-то сам метод что бы он был не такой большой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы переписал так:

```
module Omniauthable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    def self.find_for_oauth(auth)
      authorization = Authorization.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid.to_s).first
      if authorization
        authorization.user
      else
        @email = auth.info.try(:email)
        find_user # ищем пользователя
        create_user unless @user # если не находим, то создаем
        auth_user(auth) # пытаемся авторизовать и возвращаем либо nil либо пользователя
      end
    end

    def create_authorization(auth)
      authorizations.create(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
    end
    private # скрываем служебные методы

    def self.find_user
      @user = User.where(email: @email).first if @email
    end

    def self.create_user
      password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      udata = {
        email: @email,
        password: password,
        password_confirmation: password
      }
      user = User.create(udata) # здесь происходит валидация и сохранение
      @user = user if user.errors.count == 0 # если после создания нет ошибок, то объявляем переменную экземпляра
    end

    def self.auth_user(auth)
      if @user # если в предыдущих методах был найден/создан пользователь, если @user = nil(не существует, то nil вернется из метода)
        @user.create_authorization(auth)
        @user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Я поправил. В этот метод просто нужно передать переменную `auth`

Comment: ааа, точно. Он же явно вызывается, значит не privare. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: `password` тоже поправил.

Comment: а как быть с `Failure/Error: authorizations.create(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
     
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved:
       You cannot call create unless the parent is saved
`

Comment: Попробуйте последнюю версию моего кода. Суда по тексту ошибки - авторизуемый пользователь не сохранен в БД

Answer (score 1):

Не злоупотребляйте [культом Карго](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82).

Если какой-то код работает без разбивки, то пусть работает дальше.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/49563)

Comment: @Nakilon если в него не требуется добавлять функционал, то это так.

Comment: @MAXOPKA, а добавляя функционал, при куче методов начнутся песнопляски с передачей аргументов и областями видимости.

Comment: @Suvitruf: мне кажется, это вполне ответ. Просто перенос акцента от задачи к цели.